# Are there any introductory books about the relationship between art and psychology/cognition?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, music

I'd like to know more about art, music, psychology, and cognition. Since they are related to each other, I'd like to read a book with a topic covering those. Bonus if it's for beginners.

Comment: Any you found by searching on e.g. Amazon you didn't find suitable, or you could not find anything there? Any specific relationship you are interested in?

Comment: I confused on the plethora of suggested books. And I know almost nothing to start with a specific request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oliver Sacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Sacks) has an excellent and very approachable book on the topic (psychology/cognition + music in particular, less art in general): [Musicophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musicophilia).

Answer (score -1):

The [introductory reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_psychology#Introductory_reading) section in the Wikipedia page of music psychology has a lot of suggestions.